# Spectrum and eigenspaces of a linear operator in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $K:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $K(x,y)=1$ if $x+y \geqslant1$ and $K(x,y)=0$ if $x+y<1$

We define the linear operator $T_K: L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ such that $T_Kf(x)= \int_0^1K(x,y)f(y)dy$

Can someone help me to find the spectrum of $T_K$ and its eigenspaces?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to handle the "integration operator" defined via $(T f)(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$?

Comment: i don't know how to begin the exercise that's why i do not want a full solution..just some hints to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tag{1}T_Kf(x)= \int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y)dy = \int_{y=1-x}^{y=1} f(y)dy.$$

Thus an eigenfunction $f$ is such that

$$\tag{2}\lambda f(x)=  \int_{y=1-x}^{y=1}f(y)dy.$$

Let us now differentiate both sides wrt variable $x$, we get a differential - difference equation:

$$\tag{3}\lambda f'(x)=f(1-x)$$ which has solutions $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ for certain values of $a$ that I let you find.

Comment: i see..In general  it will benefit me more as a student to have a part in the solution of the exercises  in which i am stuck,that's why  i prefer hints to a complete solution... Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have corrected the functions that verify (3) (the ones I gave at first were not good, I am sorry for that). This time, I just indicated the general form. Up to you for finding the good values for $a$.

Comment: You can verify your findings by trying to apply Mercer's theorem.

Comment: As I understand by your validation, everything is OK now ?

Comment: i haven't use your hint yet because i found a way to solve this using the spectral theorem of self adjoint compact operators

Comment: The values of $a$ i think that are $a=\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2}.$

Comment: I found something somewhat different 1) for $n\geq 0$ : $a=\frac{(4n+1) \pi}{2}$ giving eigenvalues $\lambda_n=\frac{1}{a}=\frac{2}{(4n+1) \pi}$ associated with $\sin(ax)$ 2) a similar result for functions  $\cos(ax)$ but with eigenvalues $\mu_n= - \frac{1}{a}= - \frac{2}{(4n+1) \pi}$

Comment: I thought Mercer's theorm could be applied but it does not look possible because kernel $K$ is discontinuous.